# Sass migration (to libsass 3.0) generate massive selectors

Tags: sass, gruntjs, libsass

On my project, I am currently using grunt-sass 0.14.1. Everything seems ok.

When I tried to migrate to more recent version of grunt-sass, the 0.16.1 (embedding the libsass 3.0 release) my compiled css result in having massive (useless) selectors.

I saw [on the release](https://github.com/sass/libsass/releases/tag/3.0) that the `@extend` may have change. I suppose it could came from that...

But I can't manage to understand where useless selectors come from.

Do you have any tracks to find out where the problem is.

He is a cssmetrics of the same files compile with each version of `grunt-sass`:

0.14.1

- Total rules: 8355
- **Total selectors: 21679**
- Average selectors per rule: 2.6
- File size: 1.60 MB
- GZip size: 202.15 KB

0.15.0 Same as 0.14.1

0.16.1

- Total rules: 8373
- **Total selectors: 31118**
- Average selectors per rule: 3.7
- File size: 2.36 MB
- GZip size: 256.77 KB

Thank you.

PS: my scss code base is pretty big, so I don't know if pieces of scss code would be usefull.

Comment: Have you tried the 2.x version? All the 0.X are a few years old

Comment: Yes, I first tried directly with the latest version but the problem appeared. That's why I then tried with older version. The problem seems to show up only from the 0.16